# Set width of area used for left-y-axis labels?

Tags: mpandroidchart

I have 3 graphs, each with a different set of y-axis labels (for left axis). This results in the AxisLines for each graph not lining up. Is there a way to set a minimum space that the labels take up?

I've been playing with this;

```
leftAxis.setPosition(YAxis.YAxisLabelPosition.INSIDE_CHART);
```

But I don't like the overall look, even if it does result in the AxisLines aligning.